# i'm trying to get a grip on how to convert an interface from android to objective-c

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

So I have pretty recently started to learn Objective-C and at work we have been working on an android app which we are going to release on IOS later on as well so I'm trying to get an understanding on how to re-write some code into Objective-C let's take this as an example:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/*
  * Serializable is needed for sending in Android intents.
  */
public interface IMessage extends Serializable {
enum MessageID {
    // Nothing to send or reply
    NONE,
    // Client polls server
    POLL,
    POLL_OK,
    // Client internal, indicates network problems
    NONETWORK,
    // Indicates programming errors
    INVALIDMESSAGE,
    INVALIDSTATE,
    UNKNOWNMESSAGE,
    // Application setup messages
    LOGIN,
    LOGIN_OK,
    LOGIN_ACCOUNT_DOES_NOT_EXIST,
    LOGOUT,
    LOGOUT_OK,
    REGISTER,
    REGISTER_OK,
    REGISTER_NICKNAME_ALREADY_EXISTS,
    UPDATEACCOUNT,
    UPDATEACCOUNT_OK,
    UPDATEACCOUNT_NICKNAME_ALREADY_EXISTS,
    // Game setup messages
    QUERYGAMESTATUS,
    QUERYGAMESTATUS_IDLE,
    QUERYGAMESTATUS_PENDING,
    QUERYGAMESTATUS_PLAYING,
    REQUESTGAME,
    REQUESTGAME_OK,
    REQUESTGAME_ALREADY_IN_GAME,
    REQUESTGAME_DUPLICATE_REQUEST,
    ENTERGAME,
    ENTERGAME_OK,
    ENTERGAME_ERROR,
    // Game playing messages
    // ...
};

MessageID     getID();
String        encodeAttributes();
void          decodeAttributes(String data);
}
```

So I'm wondering if you have to always use an .m file together with an .h file because i'm guessing the could would be something like this in Obejctive-C:

```
@interface IMessage : NSObject
typedef enum {

//all the same

} MessageID;

NSString *encodeAttributes();
-(void) decodeAttributes(NSString data);
```

or would I have to split it up more into two files? because i'm guessing that you have to have both an .m/.h file?

Answer (score 1):

[Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) are the Objective-C equivalent to Java interfaces.

And don't use IMessage, Hungarian notation is used in C# but not Objective-C or Java.

Comment: Ok gonna read up on protocols and in the java file is named that way because of I=interface in the core project and Message for the class. Just how the naming of the interface files has been.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare something need to be used by other classes you can declare them in .h. But if you need specifically for that class declare it in .m

If you would like var's and data of another . It should be declare in .h

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep declarations is .h files (interface)  and implementation in .m (implementation). You can use interface and implementation for class in single file only if it is nested class. You can find great tutorial for serialization (archiving) here: http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

Comment: Gonna check it but basically all that the encode/decode methods do is convert booleans and ints etc to string when sent over http.